# Change CSS of the content of an iframe, that has src="about:blank", on Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, tampermonkey

I'm trying this code to apply new design on [the *Google Tasks* page](https://mail.google.com/tasks/canvas) with [the extension Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/).

When I try `html{ display: none !important }` then It displays nothing as the `html` tag is not under `iframe`.
however, I couldn't modify under `iframe[src="about:blank"]` element.
How should I modify to make it work?

---

shot 1. : Doesn't work for inside of `iframe[src="about:blank"]`

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     test
// @match    https://mail.google.com/tasks/canvas
// @match    about:blank
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle ( `    
* {color: red !important}
` );
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/603218/how-to-make-the-aboutblank-page-black-or-any-other-color-in-firefox

Comment: Thanks for the link! however, the link is for the Firefox though. I better notice the thing on the title of this post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, scripting for iframes with `src="about:blank"` can be tricky as the normal userscript mechanisms do not work the same. (*Currently*, [`@match about:blank` does not work](https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tampermonkey/issues/312), but it would be a bad idea to use it here anyway, since it would have global side effects.)

Fortunately, on Chrome, iframes with `src="about:blank"` almost always have a `documentElement` by the time a Tampermonkey script runs, so you do not normally need to wait if you are **just adding CSS**.

Here is **a complete working script**, that styles that first iframe:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name    _Style iframe with src="about:blank"
// @match   https://mail.google.com/tasks/canvas
// @grant   none
// ==/UserScript==

//-- Adjust the following selector to match your page's particulars, if needed.
var targetFrame = document.querySelector ("iframe[src='about:blank']")
if (targetFrame) {
    addStyleToFrame (
        `* {color: red !important}`
        , targetFrame
    );
}

function addStyleToFrame (cssStr, frmNode) {
    var D               = frmNode.contentDocument;
    var newNode         = D.createElement ('style');
    newNode.textContent = cssStr;

    var targ    = D.getElementsByTagName ('head')[0] || D.body || D.documentElement;
    targ.appendChild (newNode);
}
```

---

#### If the `<iframe>` tag is javascript created, or other delays hamper the above...

Use [the `iframeSelector` parameter of `waitForKeyElements`](https://gist.github.com/BrockA/2625891) to work around that.

The trick is to pick a node that always appears in the finished iframe, and pass that to waitForKeyElements.
**The node should be unique.**
But for the following example I used `.goog-toolbar:first` as a quick first attempt.

Here is that **complete working script**:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Style iframe with src="about:blank"
// @match    https://mail.google.com/tasks/canvas
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// @grant    GM.getValue
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directives are needed to restore the proper sandbox.

const desiredStyles = `* {color: red !important;}`;

waitForKeyElements (
    ".goog-toolbar:first",
    addCSS_Style,
    false,
    "iframe[src='about:blank']"
);

function addCSS_Style (jNode) {
    var frmBody = jNode.closest ("body");
    //-- Optionally add a check here to avoid duplicate <style> nodes.
    frmBody.append (`<style>${desiredStyles}</style>`);
}
```

---

Notes:

1. `GM_addStyle()` will not work in this case, so we add styles with a frame-aware function.
2. Google pages use: multiple, nested iframes; complex page (re)mangling; and HTML with poor "info scent".  In short they are evil, ever-shifting, and can be a pain to script for.  So, this simple example will work, but that's all that's in scope for this question.  For more complex scenarios, open a new question and have plenty of beer money on hand.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! however, when I've edited your `@match url` and `iframe[src="default.asp"]` part to test on  [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp), I could see the line `color: red !important` placed under `<head>` as meant to do. but, the code you gave, still not giving the `color: red !important` value inside  the `<head>` on the [Google tasks](https://mail.google.com/tasks/canvas) page though.

Comment: Chrome's built-in pages, such as chrome extension page, are impossible or least really tough thing to modify with Javascirpt as I've never saw the retouching extensions for on those, however, I don't think the [Google tasks](https://mail.google.com/tasks/canvas) is one of the built in page though, as I could retouch the site with an extension [Stylus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne?hl=en), so I've open up the extension's script files to find the hint for how the extension could make the work, but still no clue yet :0

Comment: The script works on the Google tasks page; I tested it.  But it doesn't necessarily put the style in the head section. Run the script EXACTLY as given on https://mail.google.com/tasks/canvas. You should see most of the page text colored red -- even if you can't find the `<style>` node.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I rebooted my computer and turned off all the other extensions to make it clear and I could see the change, however it has odd behavior though. when I keep press `F5` or `shift + F5` it add the `<style>` but sometimes are not. I guess it need to have waiting key as like on the `shot 2` on the post. this code probably have error as it not work, but how 
 do you think about this solution?

Comment: I'm just removed the <code>shot 2</code> from on the post. I'm still trying to make the value to return until can find the <code>iframe[src="about:blank"]</code>, however you already gave me the answer what I need so I might need to open a new question for improve it, thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: @Nam, I added answer code that should work around the timing/delay problems you report (But that I don't see).  If  they persist, and you can give us a recipe to reliably duplicate the problem, then open a new question.

Comment: I don't know why it's not working by only to make it waiting iframe[src="about:blank"] (which I've tried first), but it works now by adding the inner elements. and I guess the matter is not shown by connection speed from the Google server. Thanks for the help again!