# Load CSS is not working 100%

Tags: javascript, css

I've got this code below from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51795821/change-css-of-iframesrc-aboutblank-on-chrome/51797090#51797090), the script is for change CSS inside of `iframe[src="about:blank"]` on [Google tasks](https://mail.google.com/tasks/canvas) with Chrome extension Tempermonkey.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name    _Style iframe with src="about:blank"
// @match   https://mail.google.com/tasks/canvas
// ==/UserScript==

var targetFrame = document.querySelector("iframe[src='about:blank']");

  if (targetFrame) {
    addStyleToFrame(
      `* {color: red !important}`, targetFrame
    );


    function addStyleToFrame(cssStr, frmNode) {
      var D = frmNode.contentDocument;
      var newNode = D.createElement('style');
      newNode.textContent = cssStr;

      var targ = D.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || D.body || D.documentElement;
      targ.appendChild(newNode);
    }
  }
```

This code change the font color to red sometimes but sometimes are not, how to make this code to work 100%?

---

Shot 2.
Modified the first code to wait onload the , but still unstable as like this (I'm just refreshing the page by pressing `F5` and `shift + F5` with the second code below.) [image: It's just refreshing the page.]

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name    _Style iframe with src="about:blank"
// @match   https://mail.google.com/tasks/canvas
// ==/UserScript==

var targetFrame = document.querySelector("iframe[src='about:blank']");
document.querySelector("iframe[src='about:blank']").onload = function() {
  if (targetFrame) {
    addStyleToFrame(
      `* {color: red !important}`, targetFrame
    );


    function addStyleToFrame(cssStr, frmNode) {
      var D = frmNode.contentDocument;
      var newNode = D.createElement('style');
      newNode.textContent = cssStr;

      var targ = D.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || D.body || D.documentElement;
      targ.appendChild(newNode);
    }
  }}
```

Comment: The first thing you should do is to explain in short what you what to achieve. Beside that, in the second code block there is a closing brace missing ` }`, at the end to currently you code would not run, and  why do you have a `if (targetFrame) {`  in the load callback? If `document.querySelector` returns `null`  then `targetFrame.addEventListener`  won't work.

Comment: Thanks for review and reply, I want to make the code, which turn [Google tasks](https://mail.google.com/tasks/canvas) site font color to red, to work for 100% times, before I put actual retouching CSS code on the site. by your comment I assume I should to give return function when the if value is false or null. I'll keep try to solve, thanks !

Comment: I tried to put other line of script which for check every reload the script until the Iframe is exist, but didn't work well as I meant, so I edited the question to make it more clear. without my guess!

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Did the style tag not go into the frame? Is it there but the rule isn't applying?

Comment: Is `if (targetFrame)` always returning true? If not, the code is running too early and the page hasn't finished loading at the time an as-yet non-existent element is sought.

Comment: @skyline3000 yes, that's what I meant to say, sorry for unclear. it's not apply the `<style>*{color : red !important}</style>` for inside of the iframe sometimes.

Comment: @enhzflep 10 . Yes I thought as like that, so I put my codes which meant to "load the style after the iframe is loaded" on the post, but I didn't sure and I thought the my weird code is getting this post to hard to understand, I just removed my assumption part from this post.

Comment: Looking at your updated script - I can't see why that would fix anything. You're still trying to find the iframe element at the same point of the page-load cycle. Instead of waiting for the iframe to finish loading, wait for it's parent to finish. When _that_ event fires, you know your iframe will be available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by modified as like this.
I feel so shame that I have to keep ask everytime for probably most basic skills. the first code is made by [Brock Adams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/331508/brock-adams) post on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51795821/change-css-of-iframesrc-aboutblank-on-chrome/51797090?noredirect=1#comment90562899_51797090) bottom to the top.

Answer 1. Add Wait For Key Element.js

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Style iframe with src="about:blank"
// @match    https://mail.google.com/tasks/canvas
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// @grant    GM.getValue
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directives are needed to restore the proper sandbox.

const desiredStyles = `* {color: red !important;}`;

waitForKeyElements (
    ".goog-toolbar:first",
    addCSS_Style,
    false,
    "iframe[src='about:blank']"
);

function addCSS_Style (jNode) {
    var frmBody = jNode.closest ("body");
    //-- Optionally add a check here to avoid duplicate <style> nodes.
    frmBody.append (`<style>${desiredStyles}</style>`);
}
```

---

answer 2. with Mutation Observer by [wOxxOm on forum.userstyles.org](https://forum.userstyles.org/discussion/68664/export-a-style-to-javascript#latest)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     tasks
// @match    https://mail.google.com/tasks/canvas
// @run-at   document-start
// ==/UserScript==

const css = `
  * {color: red !important}
`;

addStyle(css);

new MutationObserver((_, observer) => {
  const iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
  if (iframe) {
    observer.disconnect();
    iframe.addEventListener('load', () => addStyle(css, iframe), {once: true});
  }
}).observe(document, {subtree: true, childList: true});

function addStyle(css, frame = window) {
  const doc = frame.contentDocument || frame.document;
  const el = document.createElement('style');
  el.textContent = css;
  doc.documentElement.appendChild(el);
}
```